# How to use the output of ettercap

Tags: encryption, gnupg, pipe, stdout

To encrypt `tshark` output, I use

```
tshark -w - | gpg -e > capture.pcap.gpg
```

How do I do the same for `ettercap`?

This command does not work

```
ettercap -M arp -w - -T //// | gpg -e > capture.pcap.gpp
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
ettercap -M arp -w - -T 2>&1 //// | gpg -e > capture.pcap.gpp
```